# Flowbite components views but the interactions doesn't work

Tags: laravel, vue.js, flowbite

I have problem with all flowbite components.

- The problem is that the components loads but the interactions doesn't work. for instance [this accordion](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/accordion/) is open and I can't close it neither can I open.
- Also the models and carousels they loads but the JavaScript (Interaction) is not working. For instance, I can't close the modal and I can't change the slide in Carousel.
- I used [this guide](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/vue/) to install
- I use vue 3, Tailwind 3 and laravel 9

**This is an example of the accordion:**

```
<template>

<div id="accordion-arrow-icon" data-accordion="open">
  <h2 id="accordion-arrow-icon-heading-1">
    <button type="button" class="flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 font-medium text-left text-gray-900 bg-gray-100 border border-b-0 border-gray-200 rounded-t-xl focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-white dark:bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800" data-accordion-target="#accordion-arrow-icon-body-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="accordion-arrow-icon-body-1">
      <span>Accordion without an arrow</span>
    </button>
  </h2>
  <div id="accordion-arrow-icon-body-1" aria-labelledby="accordion-arrow-icon-heading-1">
    <div class="p-5 font-light border border-b-0 border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-900">
      <p class="mb-2 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Flowbite is an open-source library of interactive components built on top of Tailwind CSS including buttons, dropdowns, modals, navbars, and more.</p>
      <p class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Check out this guide to learn how to <a href="/docs/getting-started/introduction/" class="text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500 hover:underline">get started</a> and start developing websites even faster with components on top of Tailwind CSS.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2 id="accordion-arrow-icon-heading-2">
    <button type="button" class="flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 font-medium text-left text-gray-500 border border-b-0 border-gray-200 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800" data-accordion-target="#accordion-arrow-icon-body-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion-arrow-icon-body-2">
      <span>Accordion with another icon</span>
      <svg data-accordion-icon class="w-6 h-6 shrink-0" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 13l-3 3m0 0l-3-3m3 3V8m0 13a9 9 0 110-18 9 9 0 010 18z"></path></svg>
    </button>
  </h2>
  <div id="accordion-arrow-icon-body-2" class="hidden" aria-labelledby="accordion-arrow-icon-heading-2">
    <div class="p-5 font-light border border-b-0 border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700">
      <p class="mb-2 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Flowbite is first conceptualized and designed using the Figma software so everything you see in the library has a design equivalent in our Figma file.</p>
      <p class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Check out the <a href="https://flowbite.com/figma/" class="text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500 hover:underline">Figma design system</a> based on the utility classes from Tailwind CSS and components from Flowbite.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2 id="accordion-arrow-icon-heading-3">
    <button type="button" class="flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 font-medium text-left text-gray-500 border border-gray-200 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:focus:ring-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-800" data-accordion-target="#accordion-arrow-icon-body-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordion-arrow-icon-body-3">
      <span>Accordion without arrow rotation</span>
      <svg class="w-6 h-6 shrink-0" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
    </button>
  </h2>
  <div id="accordion-arrow-icon-body-3" class="hidden" aria-labelledby="accordion-arrow-icon-heading-3">
    <div class="p-5 font-light border border-t-0 border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700">
      <p class="mb-2 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">The main difference is that the core components from Flowbite are open source under the MIT license, whereas Tailwind UI is a paid product. Another difference is that Flowbite relies on smaller and standalone components, whereas Tailwind UI offers sections of pages.</p>
      <p class="mb-2 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">However, we actually recommend using both Flowbite, Flowbite Pro, and even Tailwind UI as there is no technical reason stopping you from using the best of two worlds.</p>
      <p class="mb-2 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Learn more about these technologies:</p>
      <ul class="pl-5 text-gray-500 list-disc dark:text-gray-400">
        <li><a href="https://flowbite.com/pro/" class="text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500 hover:underline">Flowbite Pro</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://tailwindui.com/" rel="nofollow" class="text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-500 hover:underline">Tailwind UI</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</template>
```

**Javascript**

```
// create an array of objects with the id, trigger element (eg. button), and the content element
const accordionItems = [
    {
        id: 'accordion-example-heading-1',
        triggerEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-example-heading-1'),
        targetEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-example-body-1'),
        active: true
    },
    {
        id: 'accordion-example-heading-2',
        triggerEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-example-heading-2'),
        targetEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-example-body-2'),
        active: false
    },
    {
        id: 'accordion-example-heading-3',
        triggerEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-example-heading-3'),
        targetEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-example-body-3'),
        active: false
    }
];

// options with default values
const options = {
    alwaysOpen: true,
    activeClasses: 'bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 text-gray-900 dark:text-white',
    inactiveClasses: 'text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400',
    onOpen: (item) => {
        console.log('accordion item has been shown');
        console.log(item);
    },
    onClose: (item) => {
        console.log('accordion item has been hidden');
        console.log(item);
    },
    onToggle: (item) => {
        console.log('accordion item has been toggled');
        console.log(item);
    },
};
```

This accordion is open and I can't close it, as well as Modal or carousel to change the slide.

Comment: Please post some code or some logs so that we can help.

Comment: Could you post the javascript?

Comment: You see the problem right?

Comment: JS code Added..

Comment: I don't see the problem!

Comment: So you used and merged together two examples and just copied the code. Which is fine. I will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

this should be this

```
const accordionItems = [
    {
        id: 'accordion-example-heading-1',
        triggerEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-example-heading-1'),
        targetEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-example-body-1'),
        active: true
    },
    {
        id: 'accordion-example-heading-2',
        triggerEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-example-heading-2'),
        targetEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-example-body-2'),
        active: false
    },
    {
        id: 'accordion-example-heading-3',
        triggerEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-example-heading-3'),
        targetEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-example-body-3'),
        active: false
    }
];
```

```
const accordionItems = [
    {
        id: 'accordion-arrow-icon-heading-1',
        triggerEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-arrow-icon-heading-1'),
        targetEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-arrow-icon-body-1'),
        active: true
    },
    {
        id: 'accordion-arrow-icon-heading-2',
        triggerEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-arrow-icon-heading-2'),
        targetEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-arrow-icon-body-2'),
        active: false
    },
    {
        id: 'accordion-arrow-icon-heading-3',
        triggerEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-arrow-icon-heading-3'),
        targetEl: document.querySelector('#accordion-arrow-icon-body-3'),
        active: false
    }
];
```

Comment: It didn't work. Still the accordion is open.

Comment: Well change this to false. `alwaysOpen: true,`

Comment: @Sham you also gotta explain your use case more and it would be nice to see the JS that is actually using this. Right now you are just printing in the console when you click it. You need to do onToggle and do the close function.

Comment: @Sham any luck?